# How protected is the kid actress in Logan from the violence in the film?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, acting, logan

I just saw the trailer of the movie Logan, where a female kid has the same supernatural power as Wolverine and does some pretty bad things (nasty killing etc.).

I saw that and my hear squeezed, but in the making some sort of computer graphics should produce what we see. So my question is:

Is there any approach followed to help the kid see as less as possible of this nasty pictures? Or is it allowed by the US law to make a kid do this without a problem?

---

In general a kid with such experiences, generally speaking, may have a very difficult time being okay later...

Comment: Keep in mind, Logan is an action film, not a horror or psychological thriller. The scenes may be violence heavy, but Dafne is 12 and likely knows the difference between acting out violence and reality.

Comment: Fantastical violence is much easier for a kid to handle than real violence anyway.